# multiprocessing with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to run several timers in a tkinter window, using multiprocessing, which I never used before.
I can't figure out why when first timer is running and I start the second one, the first one stops.
The same happens when I start the second timer first and then click on any button of the first timer.
I can't make both timers run at the same time.

```
import time
import datetime
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as TkFont
from time import strftime
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import messagebox


def count_down_drink():
    global count_flag_drink
    count_flag_drink = True

    try:
        temp = int(hour_drink.get()) * 3600 + \
            int(minute_drink.get()) * 60 + int(second_drink.get())

    except:
        print("Please input the right value")
    while temp > -1:
        if count_flag_drink == False:
            break
        mins, secs = divmod(temp, 60)

        hours = 0
        if mins > 60:

            hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)

        hour_drink.set(f"{hours:2d}")
        minute_drink.set(f"{mins:2d}")
        second_drink.set(f"{secs:2d}")

        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

        if (temp == 0):
            messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up ")

        temp -= 1

# food


def count_down_food():
    global count_flag_food
    count_flag_food = True

    try:
        temp = int(hour_food.get()) * 3600 + \
            int(minute_food.get()) * 60 + int(second_food.get())

    except:
        print("Please input the right value")
    while temp > -1:
        if count_flag_food == False:
            break
        mins, secs = divmod(temp, 60)

        hours = 0
        if mins > 60:

            hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)

        hour_food.set(f"{hours:2d}")
        minute_food.set(f"{mins:2d}")
        second_food.set(f"{secs:2d}")

        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

        if (temp == 0):
            messagebox.showinfo("Time Countdown", "Time's up ")

        temp -= 1


def main():
    p1 = Process(target=count_down_drink)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=count_down_food)
    p2.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()

    root.geometry("700x500")

    root.rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure((0), weight=8,  uniform='a')
    root.columnconfigure((7), weight=1,  uniform='a')
    root.columnconfigure((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), weight=4,  uniform='a')

    root.title("2 Timers")
    root.configure(bg='#282932')
    root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

    # Declaration of variables
    hour_drink = StringVar()
    minute_drink = StringVar()
    second_drink = StringVar()

    hour_drink.set("04")
    minute_drink.set("00")
    second_drink.set("00")

    hour_food = StringVar()
    minute_food = StringVar()
    second_food = StringVar()

    hour_food.set("04")
    minute_food.set("00")
    second_food.set("00")

    # --------------- drink -----------------------------
    drink_event_name = Entry(root, width=10, font=(
        'Fira Code', 18), fg='white', bg='#5789d9', justify='center', borderwidth=6)
    drink_event_name.grid(row=0, column=0)

    drink_hourEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Fira Code', 16), fg='#99ceff', bg='#5a605c', justify='center', borderwidth=1,
                            textvariable=hour_drink)
    drink_hourEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    drink_event_name.focus_set()

    drink_minuteEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Fira Code', 16), fg='#99ceff', bg='#5a605c', justify='center', borderwidth=1,
                              textvariable=minute_drink)

    drink_minuteEntry.grid(row=0, column=2)

    drink_secondEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Fira Code', 16), fg='#99ceff', bg='#5a605c', justify='center', borderwidth=1,
                              textvariable=second_drink)

    drink_secondEntry.grid(row=0, column=3)

    drink_btn_down = Button(root, text='DOWN',  fg='#99ceff', bg='#32475a',
                            font=('Fira Code', 12), borderwidth='7', width=7, command=count_down_drink)
    drink_btn_down.grid(row=0, column=5)

    # --------------- food -----------------------------
    food_event_name = Entry(root, width=10, font=(
        'Fira Code', 18), fg='white', bg='#5789d9', justify='center', borderwidth=6)
    food_event_name.grid(row=1, column=0)

    food_hourEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Fira Code', 16), fg='#99ceff', bg='#5a605c', justify='center', borderwidth=1,
                           textvariable=hour_food)
    food_hourEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    food_event_name.focus_set()

    food_minuteEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Fira Code', 16), fg='#99ceff', bg='#5a605c', justify='center', borderwidth=1,
                             textvariable=minute_food)

    food_minuteEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

    food_secondEntry = Entry(root, width=3, font=('Fira Code', 16), fg='#99ceff', bg='#5a605c', justify='center', borderwidth=1,
                             textvariable=second_food)

    food_secondEntry.grid(row=1, column=3)

    food_btn_down = Button(root, text='DOWN',  fg='#99ceff', bg='#32475a',
                           font=('Fira Code', 12), borderwidth='7', width=7, command=count_down_food)
    food_btn_down.grid(row=1, column=5)

    # food end -----------------------------------------------------------------

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: 2 things: Why are you calling `<Process>.join()`? Second thing: Using multiprocessing/threading with tkinter can crash tkinter without giving you an error traceback so I would avoid it.

Comment: Could you please make a [___Minimal___ Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @TheLizzard, yes join() is redundant. I will remove now. Is there any way to run several timers at the same time without the multiprocessing?

Comment: @LetzerWille Look at `<tkinter.Tk>.after(time_in_ms, function)`

Comment: @Programmer, I have tried my best. Now there is much less code.

Comment: You don't need multiprocessing just to manager timers. Tkinter can likely handle dozens or hundreds. Is this really all you're doing, or are you using timers just as a simple example of something that is more complex?

Comment: @BryanOakley,  I just need up to 6 timers running, and that's all.

Comment: Then multiprocessing is far more overhead than you need. You can use tkinter's `after` method to run a function once a second to  update a timer.